# Number Of Rows Since Positive/Negative in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
   MACD
0  -2.3
1  -0.3
2   0.8
3   0.1
4   0.6
5  -0.7
6   1.1
7   2.4
```

How can I add an extra column showing the number of rows since MACD was on the opposite side of the origin (positive/negative)?

Desired Outcome:

```
   MACD  RowsSince
0  -2.3        NaN
1  -0.3        NaN
2   0.8          1
3   0.1          2
4   0.6          3
5  -0.7          1
6   1.1          1
7   2.4          2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with use `np.sign` with `diff` create the subgroup , then with `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
s = np.sign(df['MACD']).diff().ne(0).cumsum()

df['new'] = (df.groupby(s).cumcount()+1).mask(s.eq(1))
df
Out[80]: 
   MACD  new
0  -2.3  NaN
1  -0.3  NaN
2   0.8  1.0
3   0.1  2.0
4   0.6  3.0
5  -0.7  1.0
6   1.1  1.0
7   2.4  2.0
```

Comment: @QuangHoang ah I should do that